# Creating a staircase shaped tableau

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I want to create a tableau of vectors in LaTeX, like the one seen on Slide 7 in [these slides](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~danielch/linear12/lecture29.pdf).

[image]

But unlike in the slides, I want to have vectors like the one given by the code below

```
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
```

placed inside the cells. Is there an elegant way to do this, using either TikZ or tables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`ytableau`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau) package could be an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[boxsize=5em]{ytableau}

\begin{document}

\begin{ytableau}
*(red!20)\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} 
  & *(red!20)\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} 
  & *(red!20)\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} 
  & *(red!20)\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
  & *(red!20)\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
  & *(red!20)\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \\
*(blue!20)\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} 
  &*(blue!20)\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} 
  & *(blue!20)\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \\
*(yellow!20)\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
  &*(yellow!20)\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{ytableau}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RyanReich I don't know; we must be using different versions of your package. Can we meet in chat in 20 minutes to compare *File List*s?

Comment: No, I figured it out.  I'm just an idiot and didn't load `amsmath`...it's *always* loaded so why even think about it?

Comment: @RyanReich ah, I see.

Comment: I'm sort of surprised that `pmatrix` is defined with out it, actually.  If I'd gotten an unknown environment error it would have been much more obvious.

Comment: @RyanReich the problem is that the command `\pmatrix` is defined in the LaTeX kernel: `\def\pmatrix#1{\left(\matrix{#1}\right)}`.